# How to add name under image gallery?

Tags: angularjs, html, ionic-framework

HI i am displaying images as giving below from a son object. in that son object i have name for each image i need to display the name of images under the corresponding.

```
<ion-scroll direction="x" class="item row" id="galleryline1">
    <div class="first_row" id="firstrow">
        <div>
            <img ng-repeat="image in allimages" ng-src="{{image.src}}" ng-click="showImages(image.title)" class="image-list-thumb"/>
        </div>
    </div>   
</ion-scroll>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add the expression to display name of image inside the ng-repeat.

```
<ion-scroll direction="x" class="item row" id="galleryline1">
    <div class="first_row" id="firstrow">
        <div>
            <div ng-repeat="image in allimages">
                <img  ng-src="{{image.src}}" ng-click="showImages(image.title)" class="image-list-thumb"/><br />
                <span>{{image.name}}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</ion-scroll>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adjust your **HTML** like below:

```
<ion-scroll direction="x" class="item row" id="galleryline1">
    <div class="first_row" id="firstrow">
        <div  ng-repeat="image in allimages">
            <img ng-src="{{image.src}}" ng-click="showImages(image.title)" class="image-list-thumb"/>
            <h4 ng-bind="image.name"></h4>      
        </div>
    </div>
</ion-scroll>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your angular template is constructed wrong.

You need to perform the angular image iteration on the parent element. Like so:

```
<ion-scroll direction="x" class="item row" id="galleryline1">
    <div class="first_row" id="firstrow">
        <div ng-repeat="image in allimages">
            <img ng-src="{{image.src}}" ng-click="showImages(image.title)" class="image-list-thumb"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</ion-scroll>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, try this one:

```
<ion-scroll direction="x" class="item row" id="galleryline1">
    <div class="first_row" id="firstrow">
        <div  ng-repeat="image in allimages">
            <img ng-src="{{image.src}}" ng-click="showImages(image.title)" class="image-list-thumb"/>
            <h3 ng-bind="image.name"></h3>      
        </div>
     </div>
</ion-scroll>
```

Answer (score 0):

something like that?

```html
<ion-scroll direction="x" class="item row" id="galleryline1">
  <div class="first_row" id="firstrow">
    <div ng-repeat-start="image in allimages" class="image-list-thumb-img">
      <img ng-src="{{image.src}}" ng-click="showImages(image.title)"/>
    </div>
    <div ng-repeat-end class="image-list-thumb-note">{{image.name}}</div>
  </div>
</ion-scroll>
```